# Command to tell the OS Version of a container image

Tags: docker, debian, containers

I have an older docker container image of `.Net Core 3.1.1`. I think it uses debian-slim 10.2 as the OS.  I am looking to upgrade to the `.Net Core 3.1.10` image.  I think that uses debian-slim 10.6.

As I working to put together a container plan and I would like to be able to easily tell what version of debian-slim a container image is built with.

**Is there a command I can run on a container image to know what version of debian-slim it is running?**

If an example image is needed then this is one I am looking at: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.10-buster-slim`.  Another, older one, is `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.1-buster-slim`

Comment: You can use a tool like `Dedockify` https://github.com/mrhavens/Dedockify

Comment: @Hackerman - I looked into `Dedockify`.  While very interesting, it stops before it gets down to the OS level container.  And for the key container I needed to check it had a `FROM` statement that was the same and container I was trying to get the info on.  (A bit confusing).  Still it is an interesting tool, even if it is not able to give the info I need.

Comment: Actually, I use windows as my main OS. I downloaded the container image, created a powershell alias in order to check if it works, and works like a charm, you just give the `image id` and it prints all the information, even the `FROM` statement :)

Comment: @Hackerman - huh, maybe I am doing it wrong.  Are you able to get the OS level container from this image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.10-buster-slim`?  (For me it has a bunch of docker file commands including a `FROM` statement, but it is the same as the image that I am trying to get details on (`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.10-buster-slim`) and it does not have any details on the OS image version.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command seems to give the version number, but only the major version:

```
docker run -it --rm -a stdout --entrypoint cat MyContainer:1.0.0 "/etc/os-release"
```

I will open a new question about finding the minor version number on a debian-slim container.

Update:
Here is how to get the minor version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65117928/16241

Update:

Though painfully slow, this powershell script will get the linux distro and version number of a container image if it is debian or ubuntu.

```
function GetOsInfoFromImage
{
    param (
        [string] $image = $(throw "-image is required")
    )
    
    $containerId = docker run --detach --interactive $image
    # Get the basic os information from the container and put it in a hash table    
    $osReleaseInfo = docker exec --interactive --tty $containerId cat "/etc/os-release" | ConvertFrom-StringData 
    $distribution = $osReleaseInfo.ID
    

    if ($distribution -eq 'debian') {       
        $version = docker exec --interactive --tty $containerId cat "/etc/debian_version"
        
        # if there are not any man pages then we can be fairly confident that this is a slim build.
        # pulled from here: https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype/blob/master/scripts/.slimify-excludes
        $isSlim = (docker exec --interactive --tty $containerId ls "/usr/share/man/").Count > 0
        if ($isSlim = $true) {
            $distribution = "$($distribution)-slim"
        }
    } elseif ($distribution -eq 'Ubuntu') {
        $version = $osReleaseInfo.VERSION_ID.Trim('"')      
    }   
    
    # cleanup the container we had to make
    docker stop $containerId | Out-Null
    docker rm $containerId | Out-Null
    
    $finalVersion = "$($distribution.ToLower())_$($version)"    
    $finalVersion
}
```

The reason it takes a long time is that i has to create and then remove an instance of the container from the image.

It can be used like this:

```
GetOsInfoFromImage mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.1-buster-slim
```