# Get minor version of debian-slim

Tags: linux, docker, debian, containers

I am setting up my container creation pipeline and I need to be able to get the major AND minor version of the debian-slim build my container is built on.

I tried the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm -a stdout --entrypoint lsb_release MyContainer:1.0.0 -a
```

but that just returns:

```
Distributor ID: Debian  
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   
Release:        10  
Codename:       buster
```

No minor version listed.

I have also tried:

```
docker run -it --rm -a stdout --entrypoint cat MyContainer:1.0.0 "/etc/os-release"
```

but that only outputs:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

again, no minor version.

**Is there a way to get the minor version?  Does the container OS even know its full version number?**

Answer (score 3):

In fact, in the old days on Debian9, you could use `lsb_release -a` to get the minor version as next:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch)
Release:        9.5
Codename:       stretch
```

You may know, `/usr/bin/lsb_release` will finally call `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py`, the realization diff for this script between debian9 & debian10 made the difference.

- In debian9, it's next:

  ```
  def get_distro_information():
      lsbinfo = get_lsb_information()
      # OS is only used inside guess_debian_release anyway
      for key in ('ID', 'RELEASE', 'CODENAME', 'DESCRIPTION',):
          if key not in lsbinfo:
              distinfo = guess_debian_release()
              distinfo.update(lsbinfo)
              return distinfo
      else:
          return lsbinfo
  ```

  `get_lsb_release` will fetch the contents of `/etc/lsb-release`, but there is no file in debian release, so it returns none. Then the procedure have to fallback to `guess_debian_release` which will fetch the contents from `/etc/debian_version`, so you get the minor version.
- In debian10, it's next:

  ```
  def get_distro_information():
      lsbinfo = get_os_release()
      # OS is only used inside guess_debian_release anyway
      for key in ('ID', 'RELEASE', 'CODENAME', 'DESCRIPTION',):
          if key not in lsbinfo:
              distinfo = guess_debian_release()
              distinfo.update(lsbinfo)
              return distinfo
          else:
              return lsbinfo
  ```

  `get_os_release` will fetch the contents of `/usr/lib/os-release`, the contens is next:

  ```
  PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
  NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
  VERSION_ID="10"
  VERSION="10 (buster)"
  VERSION_CODENAME=buster
  ID=debian
  HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
  SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
  BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
  ```

  As it already get the version, so nolonger fallback to `guess_debian_release`, so you did not get the minor version. The advantage I guess is if not use `guess_debian_release`, it will use less IO operation, but in my opinion, really countless (Also maybe some hardcoding for guess).

**Finally**, as a workaround, on debian10, you could use next to get the same behavior as debian 9:

```
$ LSB_OS_RELEASE="" lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10.4 (buster)
Release:        10.4
Codename:       buster
```

Answer (score 2):

Should have looked a bit harder.  (Found it right after posting)

Debian does it their own way by putting it in the custom, nonstandard, Debian specific file `/etc/debian_version` found only on Debian Linux:

```
docker run -it --rm -a stdout --entrypoint cat MyContainer:1.0.0 "/etc/debian_version"
```

`<rant>`Why do they not follow the standard of using lsb_release?`</rant>`

Comment: Debian is using `lsb_release`.  Because packages are frequently updated independently over the course of a release, knowing the point release doesn't tell you anything about any package other than the `base-files` package, so asking for this information is meaningful only in highly specialized circumstances.